# Access SpatiaLite connections with PyQGIS QgsProviderMetadata (QGIS 3.10.7 LTR)

Tags: pyqgis, database, connection

I would like to list spatialite connections and access a specific connectionwith PyQGIS. For `postgres` provider it's pretty straightforward:

```
>>> QgsProviderRegistry.instance().providerMetadata('postgres').connections()
{'alkis (authcfg)': <qgis._core.QgsAbstractDatabaseProviderConnection object at 0x000001D663232CA8>, 'baumradar (authcfg)': <qgis._core.QgsAbstractDatabaseProviderConnection object at 0x000001D663232948>, 'eb77 (authcfg)': <qgis._core.QgsAbstractDatabaseProviderConnection object at 0x000001D663232E58>,...
>>> QgsProviderRegistry.instance().providerMetadata('postgres').connections()['alkis (authcfg)']
<qgis._core.QgsAbstractDatabaseProviderConnection object at 0x000001D663232CA8>
```

But the same thing for `spatialite` provider returns a traceback:

```
>>> QgsProviderRegistry.instance().providerMetadata('spatialite').connections()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
_core.QgsProviderConnectionException: Provider spatialite has no connections method
```

Same problem with e.g. `wms` provider, both are available:

```
>>> QgsProviderRegistry.instance().providerList()
['DB2', 'WFS', 'arcgisfeatureserver', 'arcgismapserver', 'delimitedtext', 'gdal', 'geonode', 'gpx', 'mdal', 'memory', 'mesh_memory', 'mssql', 'ogr', 'ows', 'postgres', 'spatialite', 'virtual', 'wcs', 'wms']
```

Shouldn't all providers accessed through `QgsProviderMetadata()`? How to list and access `spatialite` (and other) connections using this class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right. It seems that, in the future, all data providers will be fully implemented in that way (known as **Connections API**). Nowadays, some providers are not there yet. Even more if you're not using the cutting edge of QGIS versions.

FYI, running on QGIS master (built today), I can perfectly access SpatiaLite connections in the expected way:

```
QgsProviderRegistry.instance().providerMetadata('spatialite').connections()
```

---

In the meantime, there is a workaround for your use case, using `QSettings`.

List connections:

```
settings = QSettings()
settings.beginGroup('/SpatiaLite/connections/')
connections = settings.childGroups()
settings.endGroup()
print(connections)
```

Get selected connection's db path:

```
selectedConnection = settings.value( '/SpatiaLite/connections/selected', '' , type=str)
if selectedConnection:
    dbpath = settings.value( '/SpatiaLite/connections/{}/sqlitepath'.format(selectedConnection), '' , type=str)
    print(dbpath)
```

---

More details about **Connections API**: https://www.itopen.it/qgis-abstract-connections-api/