# Writing the table layer_styles in a Geopackage

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3, geopackage, psycopg2

I made a pyQGIS script to backup the PostGIS tables of my team. I needed to save each table style in the Gpkg's layer_styles.

Here's an extract of how I've done but I would prefer to implement the pyQGIS one.

```py
# Init QGIS
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.setPrefixPath("C:/ProgGIS/QGIS314/apps/qgis", True)
qgs.initQgis()
#...

# PostGIS datasource
uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
uri.setConnection(myServeur, "5432", myBase, myUser, myPass)
uri.setDataSource('public', 'layer_styles', None)
# Importing the table layer_styles
couche_styles = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(False), 'layer_styles', "postgres")
couche_styles.setSubsetString(' "f_table_catalog" = \'myBase\' AND "f_table_schema" = \'mySchema\' AND "f_table_name" IN (\'table1\',\'table2\',\'table3\',\'table4\')')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(couche_styles)
# Exporting the table layer_styles to the gpkg

#...
#exporting the other layers
#...

# Geopakagization of the gpkg's layer_styles (Empying id, f_table_catalog and f_table_schema)
connection_gpkg = sqlite3.connect(my_geopackage)
cursor_gpkg = connection_gpkg.cursor()
cursor_gpkg.execute("UPDATE layer_styles SET id = '', f_table_catalog = '', f_table_schema = ''")
connection_gpkg.commit()
cursor_gpkg.close()
connection_gpkg.close()

#...
# Quiting QGIS
qgs.exitQgis()
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: The job is done but I would prefer using QGis lib

Answer (score 1):

You may choose using Qt approach e.g using recipe from [Connecting QGIS, SpatiaLite and Python?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167707/connecting-qgis-spatialite-and-python/167712) (change import to `from qgis.PyQt.QtSql import *`)

You may also want to use the new "Connections API" mentioned in [Access SpatiaLite connections with PyQGIS QgsProviderMetadata (QGIS 3.10.7 LTR)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/368204/access-spatialite-connections-with-pyqgis-qgsprovidermetadata-qgis-3-10-7-ltr/368248#368248) combined with it [`executeSql` method](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsAbstractDatabaseProviderConnection.html#aa3d39cf7c315cfee791e2d2dbb7128b8)